# Location Manager Proxmity alert or Geofence

Tags: android, google-maps

Ok, I may sound stupid but I am confused in between [Location Manager Proxmity alert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and [Geofence](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

Which one of these is a better way to detect if the user has reached a particular location?

Comment: both are pretty much the same but the Geofence is the preferred since it is newer

Comment: @tyczj: Just because its new!!! or some performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

An important note on the Google Play GeoFencing API. I've found that the GeoFencing never intelligently retrieves locations from the GPS hardware. The GeoFence API will observe the most accurate location available from the OS or if no recent location reading is available, it will cause a location to be calculated from Wifi / Cellular. (which sucks because cellular is wildly inaccurate and wifi is often unavailable)

So to get at all responsive or accurate results out of the Geofencing API you have to set up your Geofences and then poll the GPS hardware on an interval, not even doing anything with the result received, so that under the surface you are providing worthwhile data to the OS.

I can't speak specifically to the behaviour of LocationManager.addProximityAlert but I doubt it behaves any differently. You could really use either and the results and performance will likely be identical because the heavy lifting is done by waking up the GPS manually.